# A formal English word or phrase for "badass?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is an odd question, but I was wondering if there is an English formal word connoting the same concept that the word "badass" conveys. To be exact, I mean "badass" as in someone who is maybe arrogant, morally bad, wicked, perhaps disrespectful, yet, at the same time, secretly admired for his energy, over-confidence, taking the lead, conquering qualities, etc.

Thank you.